# Log-Rank test with propensity score matched data

Tags: survival, propensity-scores, matching, logrank-test

Let's assume that I have two groups that I would like to compare in terms of death rates. One group (group A) got a specific treatment and the other group (group B) did not get any treatment. I matched the groups using full propensity score matching because the groups differed systematically from one another. Now I would like to perform a log-rank test in the basis of the matched groups and I cannot find how to do that in SPSS or R. I matched the groups with R and am left with the propensity score, weights and subclasses. Now I would like to compare the mean time until death.
Who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using matching, you can calculate inverse probability of treatment weights from your estimated propensity scores. These weights can then be used to perform a *weighted* log-rank test, as described in this article:

Xie, Jun and Chaofeng Liu (2005). “Adjusted Kaplan-Meier Estimator and Log-Rank Test with Inverse Probability of Treatment Weighting for Survival Data”. In: Statistics in Medicine 24, pp. 3089–3110.

This is implemented in the `ipw.log.rank` function in the `RISCA` R-package. Adjusted survival curves can be plotted in a similar fashion using the `ipw.survial` function of that same package. Note that the latter function is rather limited in terms of customizability (does not support confidence interval calculation etc.). You can find a more flexible implementation in the `adjustedCurves` R-package I developed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So I will calculate the inverse probability (1/PSM-score) and then following up on the log-rank test. This is brilliant. However, I am wondering whether I use the weights or subclasses that I have gotten from PSM in the first place at all?

Comment: Be careful, IP weights are not just 1/PS. It's 1 divided by the probability of receiving the treatment that they did get, in R code: `ifelse(treatment=="experimental", 1/ps, 1/(1-ps))`. (If you want to be safe, use the `get_w_from_ps` function from the `WeightIt` package to calculate the IP weights.) I don't see the need for PSM here. The weighted log rank test does all you need.

Comment: True! Ok so, no PSM at all as you said I could calculate the IPTW from the propensity scores. But I will just do a log regression, thereby get the probabilities for each person and so on. No PSM. Thanks again

Comment: That worked out great. I now have the plotted KM curves and am wondering how I can get the (restricted) mean as well as the median. There is no way to do that in the RISCA R-package, is there?

Comment: I have also tried using the adjsurv function of the adjustedCurves package but I am stuck on this error message:   Arguments 'variable', 'ev_time', 'event' and 'method' must be character strings, specifying variables in 'data'.

Comment: You can estimate the RMST and the median survival time using the `adjusted_rmst` and `adjusted_surv_quantile` function respectively. Without a reproducible example it's impossible for me to tell you what causes the error message. However, I believe that the documentation of the `adjustedsurv` function or the package vignette should be sufficient to fix the problem.